# Check if path is folder/bundle/alias in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, directory, package, alias, bundle

I come from the AppleScript land and there we use

```
alias of (info for thePath)
package folder of (info for thePath)
folder of (info for thePath)
```

to see if a path is either of the above. But I can't seem to find out how to do it in ObjC/Cocoa. I'm pretty sure it's quite easy but I fail to find any info about it.

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you use either [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

To see if a path is a folder/directory, use `NSFileManager`'s `-fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:`.

To see if a path is a package, use `NSWorkspace`'s `isFilePackageAtPath:`.

I don't know any native Cocoa way to check if a path is an alias (it's a pre-OS X concept...).
I always use Nathan Day's Cocoa wrapper for Alias, [NDAlias](http://github.com/nathanday/ndalias#readme). See `finderInfoFlags:type:creator:` in his `NSString` category.
To use it, do

```
UInt16 flags;
OSType type;
OSType creator;
if([@"/path/to/file" finderInfoFlags:&flags type:&type creator:&creator]){
    if(flags&kIsAlias){
         the file is an alias...
    }
}else{
   some error occurred... 
}
```

Well it looks unnecessarily complicated, but that's life. Alias belongs to Classic Mac OS technology, while Cocoa belongs to the NeXTStep heritage.

Comment: Thank you.

I found out that I need to use finderInfoFlags:kIsAlias type:0 creator:0 but I don't know how to give it a path...

Comment: Thanks heaps man! Note: in your code you use getFinderInfo and it does not exist. You have to use finderInfoFlags like you said a few lines higher.

Answer (score 4):

There is resource value key [`NSURLIsAliasFileKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlisaliasfilekey) that you can use on macOS 10.6+

```
NSNumber * number = nil;
[fileUrl getResourceValue:&number forKey:NSURLIsAliasFileKey error:nil];
BOOL isAlias = [number boolValue];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *path;
BOOL isAliasFile=NO;  
FSRef fsRef;
FSPathMakeRef((const UInt8 *)[path fileSystemRepresentation], &fsRef, NULL);
Boolean isAliasFileBoolean, isFolder;
FSIsAliasFile (&fsRef, &isAliasFileBoolean, &isFolder);
if(isAliasFileBoolean)
    isAliasFile=YES;
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@",isAliasFile,path]);
```

The fastest I've found. You can use it to check if it's a folder - check the link [FSIsAliasFile](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Carbon/Reference/Alias_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000146-CH1g-F16390).

Answer (score 3):

From OS X 10.6 on you can do the following to determine if a file is an alias:

```
- (BOOL) fileIsAlias: (NSString*) thePath {
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];
    CFURLRef cfurl = (__bridge CFURLRef) url;
    CFBooleanRef cfisAlias = kCFBooleanFalse;
    BOOL success = CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey(cfurl, kCFURLIsAliasFileKey, &cfisAlias, NULL);

    BOOL isAlias = CFBooleanGetValue(cfisAlias);
    return isAlias && success;
}
```

(The solution by Yahoo is deprecated in OS X 10.8)

Answer (score 0):

My way to check NSURL is an alias (works for me):

```
// url - is alias?
NSData * bookmarkData = [NSURL bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
BOOL isAlias = (bookmarkData) ? YES : NO;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I ve been searching a solution to detect aliases and symlinks using Swift 3.0 and found a response [In core Foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/URL.swift#L417)

So you can create an URL extension

```
extension URL{

    var isAnAlias:Bool{
        // Alias? https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/URL.swift#L417
        let resv:URLResourceValues? = try? self.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.isAliasFileKey])
        return resv?.isAliasFile ?? false
    }

}
```